# Oracle APEX 20.1 Inline dialog scroll to top/bottom

Tags: javascript, dialog, oracle-apex, scrolltop, oracle-apex-20.1

I am trying to add a floating button with js DA, scrolling to top/bottom of the inline dialog.

I tried with `$(window).scrollTop(xx);` and it's scrolling the page not the dialog, I also tried with `$(dialog_ID).scrollTop(xx);` but nothing happens.

Any ideas how can I work this out?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set a Static ID to your inline dialog, lets say `PREGLED`. Then use the following line and the content of your inline dialog should scroll to the bottom.

```js
$("#PREGLED .t-DialogRegion-bodyWrapperOut").animate(
    { 
        scrollTop: $('#PREGLED .t-DialogRegion-bodyWrapperOut').prop("scrollHeight")
    }
 , 1000);
```